# how can I send data and manage precess properly using C socket

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to build a simple chat room using Socket, but there is a problem I cannot solve. the socket server can receive any client's data and the server can also send data back to the client. My problem is when  I create multiple clients, the new created clients could send data to server and server can deliver data to existed clients as I expect, but it cannot work properly if the existed clients send data to server and server send the data to the new created client. the error is bad file descriptor. could someone help me, Thx.

```
#define MSGSIZE    2048
#define CLIENTSIZE 2

typedef struct {
    long _type;
    char _data[MSGSIZE];
} msgQueue;

typedef struct {
    int shmid;
    int writablePid;
    int childProcessSize;
    int clientSockfds[CLIENTSIZE];
} SockfdInShm;

void serverRun(void);
void childProcess(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in addr);
void *threadDoSend(void *arg);
void *threadDoRecv(void *arg);
int msgQueueGet(void);
void updateShm(SockfdInShm *shmLinker, int pos);
SockfdInShm* sockfdInShmGet(void);

int main(void)
{
    serverRun();
    return 0;
}

void serverRun(void)
{
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    int sockfd, _sockfd, addrlen, size;
    addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr); 

    msgQueue msg = {0};
    int msgid = msgQueueGet(); 

    //create socket
    sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if(-1 == sockfd) {
        perror("Fail to create socket");
        exit(-1);
    }

    printf("The server is running...\n");
    //enable address reuse
    int on = 1;
    if(-1 == setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &on, sizeof(on))){
        perror("setsockopt error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //bind the socket with an IP
    memset(&server_addr, 0, addrlen);
    server_addr.sin_family      = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port        = htons(1234);
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    if(-1 == bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, addrlen)){
        perror("bind error");
        exit(-1);
    }

    //listen the socket
    if(-1 == listen(sockfd, 20)){
        perror("listen error");
        exit(-1);
    } 

    int pos;
    char serverInput[128];
    pid_t pidChild;
    SockfdInShm *shmLinker = sockfdInShmGet();
    shmLinker->childProcessSize = 0;
    memset(&(shmLinker->clientSockfds), 0, sizeof(int)*CLIENTSIZE);
    while(1) {
        addrlen = sizeof(struct sockaddr); 
        _sockfd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &addrlen);

        pos = shmLinker->childProcessSize;
        shmLinker->clientSockfds[shmLinker->childProcessSize++] = _sockfd;

        pidChild = fork();
        if(pidChild < 0) {
            perror("fork error");
            close(_sockfd);
            continue;
        } else if(pidChild > 0) {
            //close(_sockfd);
            //fgets(serverInput, 128, stdin);
            //if(strcmp(serverInput, ".exit\n") == 0) break;
            continue;
        } else {
            printf("fork success, child pid: %d\n", getpid());
            close(sockfd);
            childProcess(_sockfd, client_addr);
            close(_sockfd);
            updateShm(shmLinker, pos);
            exit(0);
        }
    }

    close(sockfd);
    shmctl(shmLinker->shmid, IPC_RMID, 0); 
    printf("This server has been closed\n");
}

void childProcess(int sockfd, struct sockaddr_in addr)
{
    printf("IP:   %s\n", inet_ntoa(addr.sin_addr));
    printf("Port: %d\n", ntohs(addr.sin_port));

    pthread_t sendptid, recvptid;
    pthread_create(&sendptid, NULL, threadDoSend, &sockfd);
    pthread_create(&recvptid, NULL, threadDoRecv, &sockfd); 

    pthread_join(sendptid, NULL);
    pthread_join(recvptid, NULL);
}

void *threadDoSend(void *arg)
{
    msgQueue msg = {0};
    SockfdInShm *shmLinker = sockfdInShmGet();
    int sockfd = *(int *)arg;
    //create a unique key for msg queue
    int msgid = msgQueueGet();

    int j, r;
    while(1) {
        msg._type = sockfd; 
        memset(&msg._data, 0, MSGSIZE);
        msgrcv(msgid, &msg, MSGSIZE, msg._type, 0);
        if(strcmp(msg._data, ".exit\n") == 0) break;

        for(j=0; j<CLIENTSIZE; ++j) {
            if(shmLinker->clientSockfds[j] == 0 || shmLinker->clientSockfds[j] == sockfd) continue;
           // if(shmLinker->clientSockfds[j] == 0) continue;
            printf("send to sockfd %d\n", shmLinker->clientSockfds[j]);
            r = send(shmLinker->clientSockfds[j], msg._data, strlen(msg._data), 0);
            if(r==-1) perror("send");**//here the error occurs**
        }
    }
}

void *threadDoRecv(void *arg)
{
    msgQueue msg = {0};
    int sockfd = *(int *)arg;
    int msgid, flag;

    //create a unique key for msg queue
    msgid = msgQueueGet();   
    while(1) {
        memset(&msg._data, 0, MSGSIZE);
        recv(sockfd, msg._data, MSGSIZE, 0);
        msg._type = sockfd;
        flag = msgsnd(msgid, &msg, strlen(msg._data), 0);
        if(flag==-1) perror("msgsnd in threadDoRecv");

        if(strcmp(msg._data, ".exit\n") == 0) break;
        printf("%s\n", msg._data);
    }
}

int msgQueueGet(void)
{
    int mkey = ftok("/dev", 'a');
    if(mkey == -1) {
        perror("ftok");
        exit(-1);
    }

    int msgid = msgget(mkey, IPC_CREAT|0666);
    if(msgid == -1) {
        perror("msgget");
        exit(-1);
    }
    return msgid;
}

void updateShm(SockfdInShm *shmLinker, int pos)
{
    shmLinker->clientSockfds[pos] = 0;
    shmLinker->childProcessSize--;
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<CLIENTSIZE; ++i) {
        if(shmLinker->clientSockfds[i]) continue;
        for(j=i+1; j<CLIENTSIZE; ++j) {
           if(!shmLinker->clientSockfds[j]) continue;
           shmLinker->clientSockfds[i] = shmLinker->clientSockfds[j];
           shmLinker->clientSockfds[j] = 0;
           break;
        }
    }
}

SockfdInShm* sockfdInShmGet(void)
{
    int shmid;
    SockfdInShm *shmLinker = NULL;

    shmid = shmget((key_t)6638, sizeof(SockfdInShm), IPC_CREAT|0666);
    if(shmid == -1) {
        perror("shmid");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    shmLinker = (SockfdInShm *)shmat(shmid, 0, 0);
    shmLinker->shmid = shmid;

    return shmLinker;
}
```

Comment: Broken anyway, for the usual reasons - failure to correctly and completely handle the results returned from system calls, assuming NUL termination etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File descriptor numbers, such as those representing open sockets, are not inherently meaningful.  You can't just transfer such a number from one process to another and expect to use it to access the same file (socket, in this case).  A process inherits open file descriptors from its parent process, which is why the processes assigned to handle newer clients can forward messages to older clients, but those processes' older siblings have no knowledge of the sockets that their younger siblings are servicing.  The file-descriptor numbers of the younger processes indeed are not valid file descriptors in the older clients.

There *is* a way to copy file descriptors from one process to another via a UNIX-domain socket, but you would be better off redesigning your application so that each child process manipulates only one client socket.  You can have those processes queue messages for others (though some of the details may be a bit tricky), but you should not have them writing directly to each others' clients.

Additionally, you should make sure that the parent process closes its copy of each client socket after forking a child to handle that socket, for otherwise you'll have a bunch of unused sockets open in the parent and many of your clients.  This constitutes a nasty file descriptor leak, though you probably wouldn't notice an effect in short, narrow tests.

Comment: I am also a bit confused. all of file descriptors is created by one same parent process, though they are in different child processes. Why the older siblings can not have knowledge of newer siblings, but the newer one could know the older one. thanks again.

Comment: @XiaoPeng, a child process inherits file descriptors from its parent *when it is forked*.  You can think of it as a copy-by-value procedure, where what it copied is the underlying per-process table that maps file descriptor numbers to open file descriptions.  Subsequent changes to the parent's copy of that table are not visible to its existing children.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of:

```
pthread_create(&sendptid, NULL, threadDoSend, &sockfd);
```

You should pass by value:

```
pthread_create(&sendptid, NULL, threadDoSend, sockfd);
```

Inside the thread cast as (int) -

```
int sockfd = (int)arg;
```

When passing a variable to a thread by reference it may change, since the main thread may call this again and have a different value.

Comment: Though such a problem can occur, this is not the issue in the OP's code.  Note that the `pthread_create` calls occur inside a function, so using its own copy of the file descriptor, not directly in the main loop. Moreover, the function is called in a separate process where even the caller's copies of the socket file descriptors never change.

Comment: @JohnBollinger -Yes indeed the threads are invoked in separate processes. good point. thanks.